# How to implement watchlist functionality in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to implement a watchlist feature on my job site application. I am abit confused as to the exact eloquent queries to use to fetch the data from the `job_listings` table. Currently the user can add a job to their watchlist successfully.

**What I want to be able to do:**

View all of the jobs that the user has put in their respective watchlists with all the details e.g the Job position, description etc.

**Current DB layout:**

[image]

**Routes:**

[image]

[Bigger pic of routes here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqSez.png)

**WatchlistController**

```
   <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Watchlist;
use App\JobListing;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Redirect;

class WatchlistController extends Controller {

/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    // Need to run queries in here to get the 
    $user = User::with('watchlist')->find(\Auth::id());

    var_dump($user);

    // Then return my main watchlist view which will send through an
    // array so I can loop through it and display what the user
    // has put in their watchlist
    // return view('watchlist/viewWatchlist');
}

/**
 * Adds the username of the user that is currently logged in 
 * and adds the job listing ID that the user clicks on to the Watchlist table.
 */
public function addToWatchlist($id)
{

    $createItemInWatchlist = Watchlist::create([
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'job_id' => $id
    ]);

    return Redirect::to('watchlist');   
}
```

**Watchlist Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Watchlist extends Model {

    protected $table = 'watchlist';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'job_id'];

}
```

**JobListing Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class JobListing extends Model {

    protected $table = 'job_listings';

    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'position_title', 'description', 'category', 'job_type',
                            'city','company_name','company_url','logo_path','how_to_apply', 'expiry_date', 'status'];

}
```

**User Model**

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, CanResetPasswordContract {

    use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['username','firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'password', 'role'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function watchlist() {

        return $this->hasMany('\App\JobListing', 'watchlist', 'user_id', 'job_id');
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a id for the user?

Comment: @wiesson - No I don't because I am using the username as a primary key and it must be unique.

Comment: Hm, you could set the username to unique but still using ids in the first place, because it is much faster to query for integer ids instead of names. I had already typed the answer, but I don't know exactly how to use the laravel relations with the username.

Comment: @wiesson - I can easily add in an `id` to the `users` table if that makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the (direct) answer, but you may take a look at the eloquent relations -> http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent to see the advantages.

If you could use ids for your users, the solution looks like this: The watchlist table is the connection between the user and your jobs. Each user can track multiple jobs, so there is a belongsToMany relation between them. BelongsToMany takes up to four parameter:

1. your Model that you would like to "connect" to and
2. sql table that includes both ids of the user and the job to link between user and jobs
3. local id (user)
4. foreign id (job)

More here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many. Extend your user model with the following relation:

```
public function watchlist() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('\App\JobListing', 'watchlist', 'user_id', 'job_listing_id');
}
```

To get the watchlist, you can use (eager loading):

```
$user = User::with('watchlist')->find(\Auth::id());
```

To access to watchlist items, use `$user->watchlist`

Alternatively you can retrieve the watchlist directly in the template from the user by using:

```
@foreach(Auth::User()->watchlist as $job)
    {{$job}}
@endforeach
```

To read more about the relations, take a look at this: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals -> part 14, relations and something to read (version 4) http://daylerees.com/codebright/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Awesome! I will give that ago and see how it goes. Thank you for you help :)

Comment: I am back trying to tackle this problem. I have updated my DB picture and all of the models etc on my original post. I have tried to implement your code but I getting the following SQL error when I try and run the `$user = User::with('watchlist')->find(\Auth::id());` from the `index()` method on the `Watchlist` Controller : `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'job_listings.watchlist' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from 'job_listings' where 'job_listings'.'watchlist' in ())`

Comment: Whats the name of the ```user_id``` field? Try ```belongsToMany``` instead of ```hasMany```

Comment: Omg! You are amazing, thank you so much it works! I learnt alot while I was at it aswell :)

Comment: Haha, no you will just dig deeper in the functionality every day and learn more. I'm maybe 1-2 month 'ahead', but I had the same questions like you in the past. I would suggest to read more about the relations, because it simplifies a lot. Take a look at the laracast and codebright links!